# MVC 4 Partial Model Validation

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a standard EF model with data annotations.  I have two columns.  The first is an ID while the other is a boolean.  In the database both are non nullable.  They are both flagged however with the "Hidden" attribute.  This all works great for the UI until I go to post the form back to the server.

The model fails to validate.  I tried Steven Sanderson's suggestion to create an action filter however it failes to remove the values I do not return to the server for validation.  I ended up reverting to the following which I think is quite ugly:

```
try
{
    ModelState["LocationId"].Errors.Clear(); -- Really ugly!
    ModelState["IsEnabled"].Errors.Clear(); -- Seems really trashy to do it this way
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        location.IsEnabled = true; -- This will eventually move to my model definition
        _repo.InsertOrUpdate(location);
        _repo.Save();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View();
}
catch (DataException ex)
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("dataError", ex);
    return View();
}
```

Does anyone have any other suggestions or ideas on how to clean this up or create a better solution?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have LocationId and IsEnabled as hidden inputs in your view? If  so, are they populated there with proper values? If so, are they inside of the form?

Comment: Any reason for not using view models?

Comment: I want to avoid ViewModels where possible, just too much work as compared to defining really simply rules that apply to my Model and View.  It's a lot easier to define one Model and specify the three lines like I did rather than create a whole new class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a viewmodel and map the data you want to show/have the user input from your entity to your viewmodel. On post you would then validate the input data on the viewmodel, map it back to the entity and save it to your database.

Another way would be to remove the `[Required]` data annotations from your ID and boolean attributes, this way `ModelState.IsValid` should **not** return false

Comment: The ID field is automatically set as the Primary Key and is therefore "required" by convention.  I can handle the proper logic for the IsEnabled property as part of my repository pattern I was simply trying to avoid the work of creating a new viewModel and sucking that into another object.

Comment: I ended up using a ViewModel for simplicity sake.  It would have been nice to not have to do this.